# Make Angular working with restrictive Content Security Policy (CSP)

Tags: angular, content-security-policy, angular-cli

I cannot make base Angular2 (final) application works with the following restrictive CSP.

```
default-src 'none';
script-src 'self';
style-src 'self';
font-src 'self';
img-src 'self' data:;
connect-src 'self'
```

There are one *unsafe-eval* error in [lang.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lang-js) and two in [zone.js](https://github.com/angular/zone.js/). Could you provide a solution ?

### Step to reproduce with Angular CLI

I have created a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/nhenneaux/ng2-cli-webpack-csp). You can also follow the instructions below.

Use the last Angular CLI with Webpack 6.0.8 and the new application created with the instructions below.

```
ng new csp-test
```

Insert in the `index.html` the meta tag defining the following restrictive Content Security Policy.

```
<meta 
  http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" 
  content="default-src 'none';script-src 'self';style-src 'self';font-src 'self';img-src 'self' data:;connect-src 'self'">
```

Then serve the application.

```
ng serve
```

Access http://localhost:4200/, the page does not load since scripts are blocked by CSP.

## Errors

[image: Error in Chrome]

### lang.js

```
lang.js:335 Uncaught EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'".
```

with the source code.

```
335: return new (Function.bind.apply(Function, [void 0].concat(fnArgNames.concat(fnBody))))().apply(void 0, fnArgValues);
```

### zone.js

```
zone.js:344 Unhandled Promise rejection: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'".
 ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'".

zone.js:346 Error: Uncaught (in promise): EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'".(…)
```

with the source code.

```
343: if (rejection) {
344:     console.error('Unhandled Promise rejection:', rejection instanceof Error ? rejection.message : rejection, '; Zone:', e.zone.name, '; Task:', e.task && e.task.source, '; Value:', rejection, rejection instanceof Error ? rejection.stack : undefined);
345: }
346: console.error(e);
```

Comment: Are you by chance, using generated values in template? For example something like `<img [src]="function(input)"/>` or `<object data="{{fieldValue}}"></object>`? Angular doesn't allow unsafe values as protection against XSS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using ahead-of-time compilation solves the problem. The following command can be used to build an application working with restrictive CSP.

```
ng build --prod
```

To test it **locally** you can use

```
ng serve --prod
```

Comment: When you run ng serve:

This is a simple server for use in testing or debugging Angular applications locally.
It hasn't been reviewed for security issues.

**DON'T USE IT FOR PRODUCTION!**

Comment: Even using ng build --prod i.e. generating AOT builds, won't solve the CSP problem.

Answer (score 24):

**Edited answer for @angular/cli>=8.2**

From [this Github thread](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14599#issuecomment-527131237), one can use the `index` property in `angular.json` to control the generation of the application's HTML index:

```
build: {
  ...
  "configurations": {
    "production": {
      "index": {
        "input": "src/index.production.html",
         "output": "index.html"
       },
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

**Original answer**

I've found a way to have restrictive CSP on my production environment while still being able to use the JTI compliler for development.

- Add a second file: `index.production.html` to the `src` folder.
- Copy the contents of `index.html` to that file, and add the restrictive CSP header.

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" 
content="default-src 'none';
  frame-src 'self';
  script-src 'self';
  style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';
  font-src 'self';
  img-src 'self' data:;
  connect-src 'self'">
```

- Then, add to your `angular.json` the following:

```
build: {
  ...
  "configurations": {
    "production": {
      "fileReplacements": [
        {
          "replace": "src/index.html",
          "with": "src/index.production.html"
        }
      ],
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

This makes sure that when you run a production build, it will use the `index.production.html` with the restrictive CSP, and when you're running it locally, you can use the JTI compiler.

Comment: This is a great solution but is not working anymore. `fileReplacements` property doesn't take into account non-bundled files like `index.html`. Updated solution is https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14599#issuecomment-527131237

Comment: This combined with the updated solution in the above comment sort of worked for me. I was able to add the CSP meta into my prod build, but securityheaders.com still says I am missing them, also many (not all) of my woff2 files are now denied?

Comment: I had to add `'unsafe-inline'` to `script-src` to make it work (Angular 12)

Comment: Adding `'unsafe-inline'` to `'script-src'` doesn't break with the objective of `'Content-Security-Policy'`. Can't Angular compile and add all the script hashes to the `CSP` header?

Answer (score 3):

Using the offline template compiler should fix this.

http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/offline-compilation-in-angular-2.0
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/1744

Comment: The first link also uses zone.js that would trigger the same error.In the GitHub issue, the last comment says it does not work for all applications just simple ones.

Comment: Offline template compiler is quite new. If it doesn't work, report a bug with a minimal repo project.

Answer (score 0):

This problem happened to me with **Angular 9** deployed in a **WildFly Server**. the bug was in the *WildFly Server* configuration, in the *response-header* setted in the `standalone.xml` and it wasn`t in the *index.html* as I thougth.

`standalone.xml`:

```xml
<filters>
    <response-header name="server-header" header-name="Server" header-value="JBoss-EAP/7"/>
    <response-header name="x-powered-by-header" header-name="X-Powered-By" header-value="Undertow/1"/>
    >>> Here >>> <response-header name="Content-Security-Policy" header-name="Content-Security-Policy" header-value="default-src 'self'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'"/>
    <response-header name="x-frame-options" header-name="X-Frame-Options" header-value="SAMEORIGIN"/>
    <response-header name="x-xss-protection" header-name="X-XSS-Protection" header-value="1; mode=block"/>
    <response-header name="x-content-type-options" header-name="X-Content-Type-Options" header-value="nosniff"/>
    <response-header name="strict-transport-security" header-name="Strict-Transport-Security" header-value="max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains;"/>
    <response-header name="my-custom-header" header-name="my-custom-header" header-value="my-custom-value"/>
</filters>
```

**Note:** restart ***WildFly Server***:

```
./jboss-cli.sh --connect command=:reload
```

`jboss-cli` is located into `bin` folder of *WildFly Server*:

Answer (score 0):

Note, I got this from the Angular 10 docs, here: https://angular.io/guide/security

I solved this problem when I added this header on server responses.

```
Content-Security-Policy: trusted-types angular; require-trusted-types-for 'script';
```