# Angular: how to set up Content-Security-Policy & Trusted Types?

Tags: angular, security, content-security-policy, trusted-types

Having read [the Angular security guidelines](https://angular.io/guide/security), I would like to:

- configure [the content security policy](https://angular.io/guide/security#content-security-policy)
- enable [the trusted types enforcement](https://angular.io/guide/security#enforcing-trusted-types)

Here is how I changed my *index.html* so far:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="trusted-types angular angular#unsafe-bypass; require-trusted-types-for 'script';" />
```

Right now, I have got a lot of errors in my console:

```
This document requires 'TrustedScript' assignment.
FooService EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because this document requires 'Trusted Type' assignment.
```

My questions:

- Is it OK to define the `Content-Security-Policy` twice/for the both:
  One for the "classic" CSP configuration, one for the trusted types?
  Does it make sense?
- How do they relate with each other?
- How do I make it work both locally and in production?

  - I understood that this configuration should probably be activated only in production environments (because of JIT),
    using a specific *index.production.html* file ([see](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57396725/12292636)).
    I am not a big fan of duplicating the *index.html* just for two meta properties...
  - I also saw that I could use [the `headers` property](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/packages/angular_devkit/build_angular/src/builders/dev-server/schema.json) in my `architect.serve.configurations.production`,
    but I am not sure if it is better and/or equivalent
- Should I even use the `trusted-types`?
  It is recommended by the Angular security guidelines, but still [experimental](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/trusted-types)

I read [some interesting resources](https://christianlydemann.com/the-complete-guide-to-angular-security/), but they do not show how to concretely use the CSP attribute.
I am using Angular 13.

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple CSPs. All of them will be checked separately and your content need to pass all policies. You can have one intended for CSP level 2 and one for CSP level 3 (where level 2 browsers will ignore directives it doesn't understand).

I would recommend setting CSP as a response header. It is simpler to configure per environment and more features are available such as report-uri and frame-ancestors.

Trusted types adds another layer of security and I would implement it if possible after mastering the basic CSP.

Answer (score 0):

Just add "safevalues": "^0.1.8" to dependencies and "@types/trusted-types": "^2.0.2" to devDependencies and use it in your code like this:

```
    import {unwrapHtmlForSink} from 'safevalues';
    import {createHtml} from 'safevalues/implementation/html_impl';
    ...
    this.r.setProperty(this.inputValue.nativeElement, 'innerHTML', unwrapHtmlForSink(createHtml('some_html')));
```